# When :nth-child is :checked, select corresponding :nth-child with unlimited children

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have a layout like so:

```
<input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" hidden>
<input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" hidden>
<input id="radio3" name="radio" type="radio" hidden>

<section>
  <label for="radio1">One</label>
  <label for="radio2">Two</label>
  <label for="radio3">Three</label>
</section>
```

In CSS alone, I want to be able to check a radio button and select the corresponding label. I can do so easily if I know the number of children:

```
:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ section label:nth-of-type(1),
:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ section label:nth-of-type(2),
:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ section label:nth-of-type(3){
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Example Pen for the above example ^](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGRovy)

But what if there are `n` number of children?  One would think you could simply use:

```
:checked:nth-of-type(n) ~ section label:nth-of-type(n)
```

but that doesn't work.

**Is it possible to select corresponding children in a single selector without using JS or changing the HTML structure?**

Comment: No, it's not possible. Changing the HTML structure to put the `input` just before the corresponding `label` and then using `input+label` in your CSS is the best non-JavaScript solution.

Comment: Blazemonger has it right, but if you really can't change the HTML, you could use a CSS preprocessor to generate rules up to some reasonable value of n

Comment: I can't change the structure (though this example is overly simplified) but I can use JS.  Was just hoping to not have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to select corresponding children in a single selector
>   without using JS or changing the HTML structure?

No. This isn't possible using the current range of CSS pseudo-classes.

But, in a hypothetical situation, if you *could* change the HTML structure...

... then you could take advantage of the *next sibling* selector `+`.

**Working Example:**

```css
:checked + label {
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
}

label, input {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 48px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}

input {
z-index: 6;
opacity: 0;
}

label {
margin-left: -48px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<input name="radio-set" type="radio" />
<label>One</label>
<input name="radio-set" type="radio" />
<label>Two</label>
<input name="radio-set" type="radio" />
<label>Three</label>
<input name="radio-set" type="radio" />
<label>Four</label>
<input name="radio-set" type="radio" />
<label>Five</label>
<input name="radio-set" type="radio" />
<label>Six</label>
</section>
```

Comment: I misread your answer. You said "But if you can" not "But you can" which is why I downvoted. I'm well aware that by changing the structure I can create a selector that'd support an `n` number of radio's (as you suggested) but by doing so I'm unable to use those radio's for other other components simultaneously.

I ended up using JavaScript, but was hoping for a pure CSS solution and was curious if one was possible with today's pseudo classes. I can't remove the downvote unless you adjust your answer, but if you do I'll remove it and mark this as accepted.

Comment: Many thanks, @BenjaminSolum. Sorry that I couldn't help further. I think in complex situations like this, javascript really is the only solution. It's difficult to think of even a hypothetical CSS syntax which could handle this.

Comment: Once we have parent element combinators/selectors we should be able to accomplish this very thing.  If only :)

Comment: If you're interested in enhanced selectors, see this page on **axe selectors** - http://rounin.co.uk/projects/axe/axe2.html and this page on **axe blades** - http://www.rounin.co.uk/projects/axe/axe3.html **Axe** is a work-in-progress (which I seldom get time to work on) but it should be largely ready for distribution by the end of 2017.